# MySQL two LAST_INSERT_ID in one query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

```
Words { wordId, name }
WordGroups { wordGroupId, type}
WordSets { wordSetId, wordId, wordGroupId}
```

I need to Insert new `Word`, and new `WordGroup` and after that insert `WordSet` with 2 new ids (wordId and WordGroupId).

I make this:

```
INSERT INTO `wordgroups`(`type`) VALUES ('some_type'); 
SET @gid:=LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO `words`(`name`) VALUES ('test name');
SET @wid:=LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO `wordsets`(`wordGroupId`,`wordId`) VALUES(@gid,@wid);
```

It works, but I have doubts that this is the best way.

Does anyone have advice about better solution?

Comment: the solution you have is the best solution possible.

Comment: @RaymondNijland ok, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your code is good, I've tried that before and there is no conflict or bugs I encounter. That's the best practices.

Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the best possible solution. Just make sure this code in a transaction so that failure in anything will rollout others.